# How can I get request raw data in PHP?

Tags: php

I am designing a *server* which works as a *proxy server* in PHP. It just forwards the request from the client to server and replies the response from the server back to the client.

I want to read the *raw* request data of the client. It may include POST, GET, or multipart/form-data with *files* to be uploaded. How can I do it?

Answer (score 11):

```
file_get_contents("php://input");
```

You can see more options in *[php://](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)* ("Options").

Comment: I want the RAW data. Not the processed one. I want to forward the same thing.

Comment: Try `php://stdin`. Else, you could format a request yourself since you already know everything (you can get the headers, request-type [GET/POST, etc.])...

Comment: This method returns only content part of request. Not raw request.